# How to extract JSON path separately?

Tags: json, design-patterns

I'm new to the JSON and I'm wondering how to extract a path  from  this kind of URL-  https://www.example.com/bio-chocolate-p952
separately this way: product - bio-chocolate; product_id: p952
All I was able to come up with is following JSON pattern, which extract the path together:

```
{
    "v": 7,
    "domain": "example.com",
    "path.list": [
        {
        "$regex": "[a-z0-9-]+-[p0-9]{1,}",
        "extract": "product"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hopefully I made myself clear. Anyways thank you for your answers and time.

Have a nice day.

Michal

Answer (score 0):

If you have `pathString = 'bio-chocolate-p952'` You can use `pathString.split('-')` which will return an array `['bio','chocolate','p952']`